# Como configurar centOS para soporte ISO-8859-1?

Tags: utf-8

Tengo un problema con la configuración de caracteres en un servidor CENTOS al ejecutar una aplicación en java, no reconoce los caracteres especiales al utilizar 
UTF-8.

Comment: Puedes añadir más datos? ¿Estás leyendo ficheros desde un programa Java o recibiendo información desde la red? Algo de código sería útil para ponernos en contexto. Te adelanto que Java usa UTF-8 por defecto, pero se puede cambiar en el código la codificación

Comment: La aplicación actúa como intermediaria entre un sistema y el cliente, realizando peticiones rest o soap, ahí radica el problema al recibir los retornos con caracteres especiales. Al utilizar la codificación es_PY.ISO-8859-1 en el servidor CENTOS los caracteres son tratados sin ningún inconveniente, pero se presentan problemas con los servicios soap.